# One to many with join table with propel

Tags: orm, propel, join, orphan

I have a requirement where I need to model a One-To-Many relationship between tables through a join table like in the case of a many-to-many in propel connected to mysql. One solution I've tried is to use a many-to-many with a unique constraint on the "one" side. But this has the problem that on delete the orphaned data is not removed. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

One-to-many is the reversed relation of a normal many-to-one. In Propel you get automatically the reversed side when you use `<foreign-key>` (which is a many-to-one). There's no need to create a new additional table like in a many-to-many. See http://propelorm.org/documentation/04-relationships.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I know that it is possible to do without a join table but in our particular table model we require a mapping table between the one-to-many relationship which I know this is possible to do in some other ORMs like Doctrine e.t.c. I just haven't been able to model it right using Propel.